# Maven dependencyManagement not working as expected

Tags: maven

I have created "dependency-management" project in maven and tried to use it in "library" project (both POM below).

I was wondering, what I have done wrong, since it is not possible to declare neither "querydsl-jpa" nor "commons-text" without using dependencies.dependency.version present.

This results to error:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Then I have tried to only remove properties from library, hoping it would be "inherited" - also without any luck.

I thoungt that querydsl is managed by [spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.1.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle), but it also causes error after removing "`<version>`".

The only idea I've had in "dependency-management" is, to declare all the dependencies as "`<dependencies>`" instead of "`<dependencyManagement>`" and then exclude all unwanted in child libraries and projects, but it seems a bit complicated. Is there any other way to achieve goal: "all versions are managed in one pom.xml, libraries and apps never declare version in their pom"?

Here are full POM files for both maven projects:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency-management</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Dependency Management</name>
  <description>Project to manage dependencies</description>
  
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>3.1.5</spring-boot.version> <!-- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot -->
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies -->
        <commons-text.version>1.11.0</commons-text.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
  
</project>
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Library</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <commons-text.version>1.11.0</commons-text.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-management</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

---

Modification like this also didn't help:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency-management</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Dependency Management</name>
  <description>Project to manage dependencies</description>
  
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>3.1.5</spring-boot.version> <!-- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot -->
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies -->
        <commons-text.version>1.11.0</commons-text.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
    
  
</project>
```

This ends with errors for missing version tag for querydsl and commons-text:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Library</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <commons-text.version>1.11.0</commons-text.version> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>

            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-management</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: 1. commons-text is not a `BoM` - you can't import it, just define it as a library (i.e. remove `type` and `scope` elements). 2. `querydsl-bom` [does not contain information about artifacts with `jakarta` classifier](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/querydsl/querydsl-bom/5.0.0/querydsl-bom-5.0.0.pom) - that is definitely either `querydsl` or `spring-boot` issue. So, dependencyManagement does work as expected in your case.

Comment: thanks for hints, it kicked me where I needed to be :)